# How to design AKKA Supervisor Strategy

Tags: akka

I designed an actor system supervisor strategy as shown below.
`MyTopSupervisor` is the super supervisor of all actors and all errors escalated from the child actors. 
My question is: shall I handle all errors escalated, restarted and stopped in child actors at the top level supervisor?

Meaning:
Shall I repeat all the errors handled by the `MyOtherSupervisor` in `MyTopSupervisor` or shall I handle low level errors in `MyOtherSupervisor` and only `escalated` errors on `MyTopSupervisor`?

```
class MyTopSupervisor extends UntypedActor {

    private static SupervisorStrategy strategy = new AllForOneStrategy(2,
            Duration.create(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES),

            new Function<Throwable, Directive>() {
                @Override
                public Directive apply(Throwable t) {

                    if (t instanceof SQLException) {
                        log.error("Error: SQLException")
                        return restart()
                    } else if (t instanceof IllegalArgumentException) {
                        log.error("Error: IllegalArgumentException")
                        return stop()
                    } else {
                        log.error("Error: GeneralException")
                        return stop()
                    }
                }
            });

    @Override
    public SupervisorStrategy supervisorStrategy() { return strategy }

    @Override
    void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {
         // CREATE A CHILD OF MyOtherSupervisor
         // WATCH THE CHILD
         // do something with message
    }
}


class MyOtherSupervisor extends UntypedActor {

    private static SupervisorStrategy strategy = new OneForOneStrategy(2,
            Duration.create(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES),

            new Function<Throwable, Directive>() {
                @Override
                public Directive apply(Throwable t) {

                    if (t instanceof SQLException) {
                        log.error("Error: SQLException")
                        return escalate()
                    } else if (t instanceof IllegalArgumentException) {
                        log.error("Error: IllegalArgumentException")
                        return stop()
                    } else {
                        log.error("Error: GeneralException")
                        return escalate()
                    }
                }
            });

    @Override
    public SupervisorStrategy supervisorStrategy() { return strategy }

    @Override
    void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {
        // do something with message
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it depends on whether or not your MyOtherSupervisor can handle the exception as needed.  Do you want your MyOtherSupervisor to live past the exception?  Maybe it would help if you listed some of your concerns about the design.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on what you’re trying to do with the application.  If you have these nested supervisors (TopSupervisor -> MidSupervisor -> ChildWorkerActor) for the sake of having strong fault tolerance then I would try to catch all exceptions in the MidSupervisor and escalate the really bad ones (show stoppers, or unexpected ones) that needs to get handled by the big boss (TopSupervisor).

Think of it like how things work at a department store job or something.  You have the employees on the floor that deal with the customer.  When the customer has a problem the floor employees can’t resolve, they turn to their supervisor.  If the Supervisor can’t handle it, then he turns to the shift manager or in this case the TopSupervisor.

From the Akka Docs:

> …actors naturally form hierarchies. One actor, which is to oversee a
>   certain function in the program might want to split up its task into
>   smaller, more manageable pieces. For this purpose it starts child
>   actors which it supervises.
>
> http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.1/general/actor-systems.html#Hierarchical_Structure

**So to answer your question,** as long as you maintain a hierarchical structure, you wouldn’t want to duplicate exceptions in both supervisors because you wouldn’t have to.

I encourage you to check out Typesafe’s webinars/podcasts and the Akka documentation.

https://www.typesafe.com/resources/videos#filter:akka

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.1/java.html